# I can't do "sudo"

Tags: password, sudo, gksu, su

Let's describe it from the beginning:
I was planning to re-enable the password requirement in LightDM for security reasons. But, since my PC's been sluggish these times, it FC'd the password setup when I was entering and now I can't enter it even with combinatorics.  I have followed the tips in the Help page, but with all of them I have issues:

- I try to enter recovery mode (so that I type passwd and my name and change it), but it is a black screen just like my boot screen (because of nVidia graphic card compatibility issue), then I can't do anything
- I also tried the editting "shadow" file, but the guide talks about some commas that I just don't see where they are supposed to be.
- I even tried deletting the keyring file like it's said, but nothing happens (except that I lose the other passwords)

So is there anything I can do to have my password back? (a bonus would be stopping all this sluggish, apps not responding, etc)

Answer (score 4):

In order to use sudo you have to both use your login password and be in the admin group.

If you can not boot to a recovery shell, my advice would be to boot a live CD, mount your root partition, and set a password using chroot.

```
sudo -i
mount /dev/sdax /mnt # /dev/sdxy is your ubuntu root partition
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
passwd your_user_name
```

While you are in the chroot, make sure your user is in the admin group. You can do this by editing `/etc/groups`, add you user at the end of the admin line if needed.

Comment: Okay, Ubuntu 11.10 live CD doesn't have a GUI Terminal except from Alt+F2. Is there any way to access the CLI Terminal from there or some other way to do this?

Comment: Open gnome-terminal

Comment: @Klevin92 Or use Ctl+Alt+F2. Ctl+Alt+F7 to get back to a GUI.